# jQuery Typewriter Effect

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I am trying to use this jQuery script called Typpy Tappy Typer https://codepen.io/stevn/pen/jEZvXa/ on a slider. I was able to make it work but after finishing a certain slide, it doesn’t redo the typewriter animation.

Can someone help me loop the function so it goes continously?

Here is a snippet of the code:

```js
 function setupTypewriter(t) {
     var HTML = t.innerHTML;

     t.innerHTML = "";

     var cursorPosition = 0,
         tag = "",
         writingTag = false,
         tagOpen = false,
         typeSpeed = 100,
        tempTypeSpeed = 0;

     var type = function() {
        
         if (writingTag === true) {
             tag += HTML[cursorPosition];
         }

         if (HTML[cursorPosition] === "<") {
             tempTypeSpeed = 0;
             if (tagOpen) {
                 tagOpen = false;
                 writingTag = true;
             } else {
                 tag = "";
                 tagOpen = true;
                 writingTag = true;
                 tag += HTML[cursorPosition];
             }
         }
         if (!writingTag && tagOpen) {
             tag.innerHTML += HTML[cursorPosition];
         }
         if (!writingTag && !tagOpen) {
             if (HTML[cursorPosition] === " ") {
                 tempTypeSpeed = 0;
             }
             else {
                 tempTypeSpeed = (Math.random() * typeSpeed) + 50;
             }
             t.innerHTML += HTML[cursorPosition];
         }
         if (writingTag === true && HTML[cursorPosition] === ">") {
             tempTypeSpeed = (Math.random() * typeSpeed) + 50;
             writingTag = false;
             if (tagOpen) {
                 var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
                 t.appendChild(newSpan);
                 newSpan.innerHTML = tag;
                 tag = newSpan.firstChild;
             }
         }

         cursorPosition += 1;
         if (cursorPosition < HTML.length - 1) {
             setTimeout(type, tempTypeSpeed);
         }

     };

     return {
         type: type
     };
 }

 var typer = document.getElementById('typewriter');

 typewriter = setupTypewriter(typewriter);

 typewriter.type();
```

```css
.var-highlight{
 color: #C0AD60;
}
.string-highlight{
 color: rgba(253, 149, 90, 0.8);
}

#typewriter{
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Courier New";

  &:after{
   content: "|";
   animation: blink 500ms linear infinite alternate;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink{
 0%{opacity: 0;}
 100%{opacity: 1;}
}

@-moz-keyframes blink{
 0%{opacity: 0;}
 100%{opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes blink{
 0%{opacity: 0;}
 100%{opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<pre id="typewriter">
<span class="var-highlight">var</span> object = {
    name: <span class="string-highlight">'Foo'</span>,
    type: <span class="string-highlight">'Bar'</span>,
    location: <span class="string-highlight">'Earth'</span>,
    properties:[<span class="string-highlight">'Javascript'</span>,
                <span class="string-highlight">'HTML'</span>,
                <span class="string-highlight">'CSS'</span>];
}; </pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that the loop should reset the typed text and then retype it, a modification to the check at the end of the loop will achieve this simply:

```
cursorPosition += 1;
if (cursorPosition < HTML.length - 1) {
    setTimeout(type, tempTypeSpeed);
} else {
    // This new code will reset the output to the start again
    cursorPosition = 0;
    t.innerHTML = "";
    setTimeout(type, tempTypeSpeed);
}
```

What this does is '*reset*' the output once the final character has been typed.  The whole output then starts again.

Here's a working snippet:

```js
function setupTypewriter(t) {
     var HTML = t.innerHTML;

     t.innerHTML = "";

     var cursorPosition = 0,
         tag = "",
         writingTag = false,
         tagOpen = false,
         typeSpeed = 100,
        tempTypeSpeed = 0;

     var type = function() {
        
         if (writingTag === true) {
             tag += HTML[cursorPosition];
         }

         if (HTML[cursorPosition] === "<") {
             tempTypeSpeed = 0;
             if (tagOpen) {
                 tagOpen = false;
                 writingTag = true;
             } else {
                 tag = "";
                 tagOpen = true;
                 writingTag = true;
                 tag += HTML[cursorPosition];
             }
         }
         if (!writingTag && tagOpen) {
             tag.innerHTML += HTML[cursorPosition];
         }
         if (!writingTag && !tagOpen) {
             if (HTML[cursorPosition] === " ") {
                 tempTypeSpeed = 0;
             }
             else {
                 tempTypeSpeed = (Math.random() * typeSpeed) + 50;
             }
             t.innerHTML += HTML[cursorPosition];
         }
         if (writingTag === true && HTML[cursorPosition] === ">") {
             tempTypeSpeed = (Math.random() * typeSpeed) + 50;
             writingTag = false;
             if (tagOpen) {
                 var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
                 t.appendChild(newSpan);
                 newSpan.innerHTML = tag;
                 tag = newSpan.firstChild;
             }
         }

         cursorPosition += 1;
         if (cursorPosition < HTML.length - 1) {
           setTimeout(type, tempTypeSpeed);
         } else {
            cursorPosition = 0;
            t.innerHTML = "";
           setTimeout(type, tempTypeSpeed);
          }

     };

     return {
         type: type
     };
 }

 var typer = document.getElementById('typewriter');

 typewriter = setupTypewriter(typewriter);

 typewriter.type();
```

```css
.var-highlight{
 color: #C0AD60;
}
.string-highlight{
 color: rgba(253, 149, 90, 0.8);
}

#typewriter{
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Courier New";

  &:after{
   content: "|";
   animation: blink 500ms linear infinite alternate;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink{
 0%{opacity: 0;}
 100%{opacity: 1;}
}

@-moz-keyframes blink{
 0%{opacity: 0;}
 100%{opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes blink{
 0%{opacity: 0;}
 100%{opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<pre id="typewriter">
<span class="var-highlight">var</span> object = {
    name: <span class="string-highlight">'Foo'</span>,
    type: <span class="string-highlight">'Bar'</span>,
    location: <span class="string-highlight">'Earth'</span>,
    properties:[<span class="string-highlight">'Javascript'</span>,
                <span class="string-highlight">'HTML'</span>,
                <span class="string-highlight">'CSS'</span>];
}; </pre>
```